# ADB not finding device with Galaxy S8 and Windows 7

Tags: google-play-store, adb, 7.0-nougat, android-sdk, samsung-galaxy-s-8

I'm trying to get my Galaxy S8 to work with unity for gear VR development but I cannot seem to get ADB to find the phone.

I've enabled USB debugging in development options and also have the latest version of Android Studio and the SDK, I've also installed the Android 7.0 package in Android Studio and the windows USB drivers from that, I've also reset both the phone and computer after one suggestion, one person even suggested updating the USB drivers for the phone in device manager on windows to the drivers(Android_winusb) in the SDK folder but it says it cannot find any relevant drivers, also have tried adb kill-server and adb start-server.

Nothing I do seems to help at all. Also I really don't want to have to root the phone as that voids any warranty but from everything I've read there's no need to do that in order to get this working.

Comment: Samsung phones are often a bit funny with USB: you might need to install a Samsung-specific driver on your PC.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, i didnt know that.

Ive never heard of anyone mention a Samsung specific driver in all the videos and docs ive read so not to sure about that.

Comment: Maybe it is on charge only. Just press or long press on the device where it states connected and switch to data transfer.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but im already in data transfer mode

Comment: How about the path to the terminal?

Comment: Im not sure i follow? im using windows so do you mean CMD window?

Comment: See here for Samsung drivers http://www.samsungusbdrivers.net/2017/03/samsung-galaxy-s8-usb-driver-for-windows.html?m=1. Install them after the device is disconnected, reboot device and PC - connect and try

Comment: Yes, is the path variable correct to the cmd window you are working from. Also are you opening the cmd window with elevated privileges or admin?

Comment: That page doesnt seem very legitimate lol, im sure if samsung supports unity dev there would be a more legit site?

Comment: Yes it is correct, if i simply type adb it comes up with all the options but when i type adb devices the device list is empty, im also running CMD in admin mode

Comment: I can transfer files to and from my phone via pc so ive been told its not a driver issue but not sure once again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to connect your phone to your PC, and on your computar to go on Device Manager in control pannel and remove devices related to your smartphone.

Then, disconnect the smartphone from you PC.

Restart your PC and your phone.

Connect again your Phone to your PC.

Another try:
Simply disable USB Debugging, while connected to PC.
Re-enable It and connect to your PC.

Comment: My god thankyou so so much, the first option worked perfectly find albeit with having to reinstall the adb drivers from the android sdk but ive finally got it running so thankyou again

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was to go to Settings -> Developer Options -> Revoke USB debugging authorizations in my Galaxy S8+.

Answer (score 1):

Yep I forgot a step.  You have to "enable developer options" then go to "developer options" on the (S7 in my case) and enable "USB debugging".

Answer (score 0):

Google Driver works for Nexus, HTC, etc. For Samsung, I needed to find the correct SAMSUNG drivers and install them manually.

As long as:

- The appropriate SAMSUNG driver has been manually installed
- The device is in developer mode and
- USB debugging is active on the device

The PC should pick up the phone in ADB (when the PC has correctly recognised the phone, you should have a message on the Samsung device asking you to trust it).  When the device trusts the PC, and the correct drivers are installed, it should show up in `adb devices`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a new MacBook (2016 and newer) and are having this problem, make sure to try using all available USB-C ports. I believe only the Thunderbolt-capable ports will recognize the phone.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that runs into this issue (I was struggling with this for weeks, before I found this tip...)
Try to use a USB2 port instead of a USB3 port. That worked for me. (Samsung Note 8, Windows 10.)